# Extjs create form items with json store

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have created a form panel view and I will create some form items iside this panel. The communication to the store, controller and model works fine but how can I create the items in the view?

**Json array (retrieved from external service):**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "ff",
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "allowBlank": false,
        "fieldLabel": "labelText1"
    },
    {
        "name": "fsdsdf",
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "allowBlank": false,
        "fieldLabel": "labelText2"
    }
],
"msg": "Unknown",
"success": true
}
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Forms', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.Form',
model: 'myApp.view.FormModel',

constructor: function(config) {
    var me = this;

    config = config || {};

    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'url_to_service',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                successProperty : 'success'
            }
        },        

        storeId: 'formStore'

    }, config)]);    

    // console.error("store loaded");
    // console.info(me);
}
});
```

**model**

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.FormModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

data: {
    name: 'myApp'
}
});
```

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.FormController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.form',

init: function(application) {
    var store = new myApp.store.Forms();

    store.on("metachange", metaChanged, this);

    function metaChanged(store, meta) {
        var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form')[0];
        grid.fireEvent('metaChanged', store, meta);
    };

    this.control({
        "form": {
            metaChanged: this.handleStoreMetaChange
        }
    });    
},

handleStoreMetaChange: function(store, meta) {
    var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form')[0];
    form.reconfigure(store, meta.data);
}
});
```

At least the **view** where I want to create the items from the store.

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.Form', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'form',

controller: "form",

viewModel: {
    type: "form"   
},

title: 'form',
bodyPadding: 10,
autoScroll: true,

defaults: {
    anchor: '100%',
    labelWidth: 100
},


// How can I add form items here? 


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your view you'll need to create a function that matches the **form.reconfigure(store, meta.data)** call you are making in your controller.

And in that function you can call the form's **add** function to add items to the form. As you are already supplying the xtype and configuration parameters in the data structure each item can be passed to the add function as it. It would look something like the below code...

```
reconfigure: function(store, data) {                
    var me = this;
    Ext.each(data, function(item, index) {
        me.add(item);
    });
}
```

I have knocked together an [Example Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ovh) that shows this working. I just mocked out the loading of the data and 'metachange' event as it was easier to get the demo working.

Comment: Special upvote for suggesting that the logic to render the items goes in the view, not in a controller, I'm so tired of people making fat controllers in Ext. My only suggestion is that you call the reconfigure method from the store's metachange, not the form's, in the current code, there's no reason for the view to have a metachange event

Comment: Here's a slightly modified version of your code to teach the OP some best practices: Create classes for your components, don't use globals (like StoreMgr), don't create unnecessary events: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ovj

Comment: I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.getView(...).getStore is not a function" from the controller.